# Code to do Tolerance Analysis

Tags: c, arrays, input

So, I'm trying to build this code and it crashes somewhere in my second custom function. I'd also like to print out the content of file "tin.txt", but anything with EOF seems to crash it. I'm coding in C.

It seems like just junk is getting into my arrays. I need to use string tok anyway, any hints for that?
**EDIT**
Thanks for all your help so far.
I've put in most of the suggested changes, and my compiler (codeblocks, in case it matters) has stopped screaming in pain. 
Now I'm just struggling to get the information into the arrays using strtok, I just can't figure out how to make it work. (I'm also unsure if I should ask a second question at this point or just edit this on, I just edited this one.)

```html
/*************************************************************************

3/25/2015
This program takes in a file of the format
    PART,2.000,-1,0.050,V
    PART,0.975,-1,0.025,V
    PART,3.000,+1,0.010,F
    GAP,0.000,0.080
does the tolerance analysis
**************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ARRAYSIZE 100
void input(float *nom,float *tollerance,int *SIGNS,char *V_F,float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum);
void toleracningPt1(int size, float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum);
int main(){
    /**Decs**/
    float nom[ARRAYSIZE]; //holds the nominal values (2.00, .975 ect)
    float tollerance[ARRAYSIZE]; //holds the third value (.05, .025, ect)
    int SIGNS[ARRAYSIZE]; // signifies if the value goes up or down
    char V_F[ARRAYSIZE]; // F things cannot be changed, V things can be
    int size=0;

    float Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum;
    /**custom functions**/
    input( nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
    toleracningPt1(size, nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
    }
 /***********************************************************************************************************/
void input(float *nom,float *tollerance,int *SIGNS,char *V_F,float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum){

    const char *delimiter_characters = " ";
    const char *filename = "tin.txt";
    FILE *input_file = fopen( filename, "r" );
    char buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
    char *last_token;

    printf("File Data\n");
    /* usual error check*/
    if( input_file == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename );
    }else{

        while( fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, input_file) != NULL ){// while there is stuff to do this with
            last_token = strtok( buffer, delimiter_characters );
            while( last_token != NULL ){//same song..
                printf( "%s\n", last_token );
                last_token = strtok( NULL, delimiter_characters );// clear out last_token
            }

        }


        fclose( input_file );

    }


}
/*****************************************************************************************************************/
void toleracningPt1(int size, float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum)
{
    int x;
    float Act_Gap, Act_Tollerance, Maximum_Gap = 0.0, Minnimum_Gap = 0.0;
    for ( x=0, Act_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){   //does tolerance math
                Act_Gap = Act_Gap + (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]);
    }
    for ( x=0, Act_Tollerance = 0; x<size; x++){
                    Act_Tollerance = Act_Tollerance + (tollerance[x]);
    }
    for (x= 0, Maximum_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){
                    Maximum_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]+tollerance[x])+Maximum_Gap;
                    Minnimum_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]-tollerance[x])+Minnimum_Gap;
    }

    printf("Actual Gap Mean: %.3f\"\n", Act_Gap);  //printing
    printf("Actual Gap Tolerance: %.3f\"\n", Act_Tollerance);
    if (Maximum_Gap > Spec_Maximum){
        printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
    }
    if (Maximum_Gap < Spec_Maximum){
        printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
    }
    if (Minnimum_Gap > Spec_Minnimum){
        printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
    }
    if (Minnimum_Gap < Spec_Minnimum){
        printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of saying "crashes somewhere", use your debugger to find out which line causes the error.

Comment: have you actually compiled this program?  there are numerous errors and warnings raised by the compiler (all warnings should be enabled when compiling)  There are so many (serious) warnings raised I'm not even going to try to list them all here

Comment: the second parameter of the 'for' loop in the input() function is testing 'status'.  But 'status' has not yet been set to any specific value, so the program is testing garbage and looking for 0 to exit the loop.  the result is the program may (or may not) actually input any data  This is just one of many warnings about using uninitialized variables

Comment: there are several warnings about unused variables, for instance 'Act_Tollerance' is unused.   Fix the warnings, post the corrected code.  Then we could probably help you debug the logic problems

Comment: it would help in the understanding of your code if you declared only one variable per statement (and perhaps even added comments as to what the variable is used for)

Comment: there are lots of 'magic' numbers, especially the value '100' in the code.  Much better to #define that value with a meaningful name and then use that meaningful name in place of '100' in the code

Comment: function names need to be readable and meaningful.  so what is 'toleracningPt1'

Comment: for good programing practice and expected code naming...  use 'camel' case for variable and function names and all CAPS for const NAMES and #define NAMES

Comment: the program will generate buffer overflow (resulting in undefined behaviour) if the number of 'part' records is greater than 100.  This can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: Thanks to everyone! 
It compiles and runs and then crashes- so my compiler didn't give me a line. It might be a segfault from EOF, like you guys suggested.
The "Magic" number was given in the assignment. I also ran into problems with #define last semester in arduino C, is it safe to use in normal C?
I'll make the stylistic changes you guys suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I see problems with `input` function:

- loop `for (i=0; status != EOF; i++)` can lead to segmentation fault in case your file `tin.txt` have more than 100 lines (`nom` and other arrays have fixed size).
- you send `float Spec_Minnimum` and `float Spec_Maximum` as arguments to `input`, but expect to receive values after function finished... you will not receive. I must change arguments type for these parameters and `scanf` like :

  ```
  float input(float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float * p_Spec_Minnimum,float * p_Spec_Maximum)

     . . .

  fscanf(FTIN, "GAP,%f,%f\n", p_Spec_Minnimum, p_Spec_Maximum);
  ```

  so call the function `input` as `input( nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, &Spec_Minnimum, &Spec_Maximum);`
- you save value returned by `fsacnf` to `status` but you do not check the status of first `fscanf`... strange coding style
- function `input` has type `float`, but in error case it returns `1` (integer value), and returns NOTHING if no error with file opening
- after function `input` finish `main` function has no information about how much lines were read from file, and how much elements were stored in arrays.

2) Before using data it is a good idea to see this data at screen, so you need function to print data that was read from file.

So I propose the following functions for `input` and data `output`:

```cpp
// returns the number elements stored in arrays
int input(float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float* p_Spec_Minnimum,float* p_Spec_Maximum)
{
    int status = 0, i,c;
    FILE *FTIN;
    FTIN = fopen ("tin.txt", "r");

    if (FTIN == NULL){    //file empty/broken error
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return (-1);
    }
    /******/
    else{
        for (i=0; status != EOF && i < 100; ){  //reads until EoF, even though some guy on stackoverflow taught me it's bad
            status = fscanf(FTIN,"PART,%f,%d,%f,%c\n", &nom[i], &SIGNS[i], &tollerance[i], &V_F[i]); //scans for a part
            if(status == 4)
            {
                i++;
            }
            status = fscanf(FTIN, "GAP,%f,%f\n", p_Spec_Minnimum, p_Spec_Maximum);  //scans for a gap
            printf("Reading Info Into Arrays\n");
            }
        fclose(FTIN);
        return i;
        }
}
// output arrays in special format
void output(int size, float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
          printf("PART,%f,%d,%f,%c\n", nom[i], SIGNS[i], tollerance[i], V_F[i]);
    }
    printf("GAP,%f,%f\n", Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
}
```

3) size of your arrays must be known in your `toleracningPt1` function, so  make it as follows:

```cpp
float toleracningPt1(int size, float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum)
{
    int x;
    float Act_Gap, Act_Tollerance, Maximum_Gap = 0.0, Minnimum_Gap = 0.0;
    for ( x=0, Act_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){   //does tolerance math
                Act_Gap = Act_Gap + (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]);
    }
    for ( x=0, Act_Tollerance = 0; x<size; x++){
                    Act_Tollerance = Act_Tollerance + (tollerance[x]);
    }
    for (x= 0, Maximum_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){
                    Maximum_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]+tollerance[x])+Maximum_Gap;
                    Minnimum_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]-tollerance[x])+Minnimum_Gap;
    }

    printf("Actual Gap Mean: %.3f\"\n", Act_Gap);  //printing
    printf("Actual Gap Tolerance: %.3f\"\n", Act_Tollerance);
    if (Maximum_Gap > Spec_Maximum){
        printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
    }
    if (Maximum_Gap < Spec_Maximum){
        printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
    }
    if (Minnimum_Gap > Spec_Minnimum){
        printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
    }
    if (Minnimum_Gap < Spec_Minnimum){
        printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
    }
}
```

And now your main function will be

```cpp
int main(void){
    /**Decs**/
    float nom[100], tollerance[100];
    int SIGNS[100];
    char V_F[100];
    //int status, i, x;
    float Act_Gap, Act_Tollerance, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum;
    /**custom functions**/
    int size = 0;
    size = input( nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, &Spec_Minnimum, &Spec_Maximum);
    output( size, nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
    toleracningPt1(size, nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
}
```

P.S.: I do not know what the "Tolerance Analysis" is, but after my fixes, for file that you have provided as example, your program output the result:

```
 Actual Gap Mean: 0.025"
 Actual Gap Tolerance: 0.085"
 The maximum gap (0.110") is (Greater) than specified (0.080")
 The minimum gap (-0.060") is (Less) than specified (0.000")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int input(float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float *Spec_Minnimum,float *Spec_Maximum);

int main(void){
    float nom[100], tollerance[100], Spec_Minnimum=0, Spec_Maximum=0;
    int SIGNS[100];
    char V_F[100];
    int i, n;
    n = input( nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, &Spec_Minnimum, &Spec_Maximum);
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
        printf("part,%f, %d, %f, %c\n", nom[i], SIGNS[i], tollerance[i], V_F[i]);
    }
    printf("gap,%f, %f\n", Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
    return 0;
}

int input(float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float *Spec_Minnimum,float *Spec_Maximum){
    int status, i;
    FILE *FTIN;
    FTIN = fopen ("tin.txt", "r");

    if (FTIN == NULL){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        for(i=0;;){
            if((status = fscanf(FTIN," PART,%f,%d,%f,%c", &nom[i], &SIGNS[i], &tollerance[i], &V_F[i]))==4){
                ++i;
            } else if((status = fscanf(FTIN, " GAP,%f,%f", Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum))==0){
                fgetc(FTIN);//drop one
            } else if(status == EOF){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(FTIN);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: this is much better.  However, 'status' is still declared as a local variable in the main() function and is still unused

Comment: @user3629249 sure, I delete `status` at main. thanks.

Comment: in the function: input(), the calls to fscanf() are nicely written, however, fscanf() does not 'ever' return EOF, it does return the number of successful input/conversions, or 0 if no conversions successful, so the line: 'else if(status == EOF) will never be true.  Suggest placing the literal for a comparison on the left, so the compile can catch oops like if only one '=' is used instead of '=='

Comment: suggest reading the FTIN file line by line into  a buffer using getline() or fgets() and when such call is successful, parcing the individual fields from the buffer, perhaps using sscanf()

Comment: @user3629249 "`if(status == EOF)` will never be true." : you misunderstand my code. [DEMO can  break](http://ideone.com/rNUOA5)